# Can I select a update from database field

Tags: mysql

What I am trying to do is to select a update from a portion of my site where users upload pictures and I know I have to create a field for that in my database but first I was wondering to know if I can use this syntax like:

```
SELECT UPDATE 
FROM photos 
WHERE album LIKE BINARY 'loggedin_avatar'  
ORDER BY datemade ASC
```

so is this a right syntax? also where can I learn about filtering the files being uploaded to my site. Generally filtering the files being uploaded.

Comment: It's not correct syntax

Comment: Ref:- `http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp` for `select` and `http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp` for `update`

Comment: Do you mean `update` is a column name? then you can escape it using the backtick character `

Comment: do operation differently...

Answer (score 1):

If `UPDATE` is a column in table `photos` then

use this

```
SELECT `update` 
FROM photos 
WHERE album LIKE BINARY 'loggedin_avatar'  
ORDER BY datemade ASC
```

if `UPDATE` is not column then use this

```
SELECT * 
FROM photos 
WHERE album LIKE BINARY 'loggedin_avatar'  
ORDER BY datemade ASC
```

Comment: Why are you answering with the exact same point as in my answer?

Comment: @Starx We answered the question almost same time but I made edit afterwards So thats why you see my answer as answered 3 min ago and yours 5 mins.

Answer (score 0):

*No, that is not the correct syntax.* `SELECT` and `UPDATE` are two different query statements.

If you trying to select a field called `update` from your database table, then you have to quote them

```
SELECT `update` FROM photos WHERE album LIKE BINARY 'loggedin_avatar' ORDER BY datemade ASC";
```

If you are trying to select a updated row after updating them, you have to send mulitple statements.

- First update the rows
- Select the updated row which the help of a primary key field.